# How can I transform the keys of a dictionary into a one-columned pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, key

I would like to get the keys (not the values), and create a single columned dataframe from these keys.

I currently have:

```
dictionary = {"Eva": "Person", "Xior": "Building", "Potatoes": "Food", "Dog": "Animal"} 

## my current code is: 
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(list(dictionary.items())) 
df1
```

intended output:

```
       Word
0      Xior
1       Dog
2       Eva
3  Potatoes
```

For the moment, I am only able to get the full dictionary (keys, values) as a pandas df, not just the keys. I also had to transform the dictionary into a list first otherwise I would get a ValueError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
pd.DataFrame(list(dictionary),columns=['word'])
```

or

```
pd.Series(list(dictionary)).to_frame('word')
```

Output:

```
       word
0       Eva
1      Xior
2  Potatoes
3       Dog
```

Answer (score 4):

Just this simple line:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(dictionary))
```

```
Out[5]: 
          0
0       Eva
1      Xior
2  Potatoes
3       Dog
```

Answer (score 3):

you can just call the key in a dict comprehension :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({k for k,v in dictionary.items()},columns=['Word'])
print(df)
       Word
0      Xior
1       Dog
2       Eva
3  Potatoes
```

or as rafaelc kindly pointed out :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary.keys(),columns=['Word'])
```